# Show iAds Continuosly in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am working on application in which i have to show iAds continuously. Can anyone tell me how can i set iAds that continuously stays on screen.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to take iAd in to the application Delegate View and set is bring subview to front.
    In Application Delegate add this line

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{

    [self createAdBannerView];

}

- (void)createAdBannerView
{

    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");

    if (classAdBannerView != nil) 

    {
        self.adBannerView = [[[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        [_adBannerView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32, nil]];

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) 
        {
            [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32];
        } 
        else
        {
            [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];            
        }

        if(DeviceFlag == 1)
        {
            [_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0, -100)];

        }
        else
        {
            [_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0, -70)];

        }
        //[_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0, -[self getBannerHeight])];
        [_adBannerView setDelegate:self];

        [viewController.view addSubview:_adBannerView];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:_adBannerView];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you should only show iAd banner when it has it's contents loaded. And there's no guarantee that contents will be available for you 24/7.

You could however provide an alternate content (house ads or ads from other source) for when iAd banner has no content.

Note that in this case you have to hide iAd banner and show a custom banner on it's place.

As a source of alternate content you can take a look at:

[mobiclix](http://www.mobclix.com/)

[admob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/)